# datos no esperados en consulta a mysql LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ventas` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `precio` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `ventas` VALUES
(1, 'manzana', 2),
(2, 'pera', 3),
(3, 'manzana', 2),
(4, 'durazno', 5),
(5, 'pera', 3);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pagos` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `venta_id` int NOT NULL,
  `pagado_por` int NOT NULL,
  `fecha` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `monto` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `pagos` VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '5/01/2021', 1),
(2, 1, 1, '5/01/2021', 1),
(3, 2, 1, '5/01/2021', 3),
(4, 3, 1, '5/01/2021', 2),
(5, 4, 2, '5/01/2021', 5),
(6, 5, 2, '5/01/2021', 3);
```

como se aprecia dos tablas relacionadas una es de las ventas y el otro de los pagos de dichas ventas, la relaciona seria en ventas.id y pagos.ventas_id el primer pago en la tabla pagos se realizo en dos partes de $1. La consulta que hago es esta:

```
SELECT 
SUM( COALESCE( v.precio, 0 ) ) total, 
SUM( COALESCE( p.monto, 0 ) ) pagado 
FROM pagos p
LEFT JOIN ventas v ON v.id = p.venta_id WHERE p.pagado_por = 1
```

me da como resultado esto, cuando se requiere que ambos sean el mismo monto. cual seria la consulta adecuada para sacar el mismo monto. gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

<kbd>[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9da5ae/8/0)</kbd>

Comment: Buenas @Guto C Cayro, la propera pregunta intenta pegar código en lugar de imágenes. Para facilitar la faena a los buscadores ;) Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente estás buscando algo así:

```
SELECT SUM(precio) vendido,SUM(pagado) pagado
  FROM (
    SELECT venta_id,SUM(monto) pagado
      FROM pagos GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 RIGHT JOIN ventas v ON venta_id=v.id;
```

Obteniendo:

```
+---------+--------+
| vendido | pagado |
+---------+--------+
|      15 |     15 |
+---------+--------+
```

El problema es que combinabas antes de agrupar, por eso te aparecían precios duplicados que después sumabas

Answer (score 1):

Para ver el comportamiento de esta consulta puedes quitar los agregados y hacer un `Select *`. Verás que aparecen 6 filas, duplicando una venta. Esto es lo que va a sumar al realizar el `SUM`.

Para evitarlo puedes hacer los cálculos por separado agrupándolos por el mismo concepto:  `venta_id`:

```
select SUM(a.total) as total, SUM(b.monto) as monto
FROM (
   Select id, SUM(precio) as total
   from ventas
   group by id
) a
left join (
   Select venta_id, SUM(monto) as monto
   from pagos
   group by venta_id
) b on a.id = b.venta_id
```